# How to print orizzontally in Python?

Tags: python, printing, ascii-art

I want to include some ASCII art in my code to be printed as a logo and make my program prettier.
I chosen two proper ASCII art (drawings) and a text.
I would like to design a logo with the ASCII art text in the middle and the "images" at the side. Both elements have the same height, but print("""  """) just prints them vertically.
I would like to follow a scheme like this:

```py
###         ###
# #   TEXT  # #
###         ###
```

So I have to use 3 separate print() functions, but calling

```
print('ART1') 
print('TEXT') 
print('ART2')
```

results in the contents being printed vertically, one at a time.

How can I print separate things orizontally?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the problem with it?

Comment: I tried to put them in 3 print( """  """) statements, but it obviously prints them vertically. If I try to paste it all in the same print, it will just scrumble it all because of indentation

Comment: print(""" """) prints a space ... showing the exact code you have tried will be sure helpful to see how its output differs from what you want to achieve. See some hints towards formatted printing here https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/